# Symfony 2 problems reading security.yml values

Tags: symfony, parameters, yaml

I need to read the value of one parameter of the security.yml file from inside the application.

I tried the following to get the list of all the parameters

```
$parameters=$this->container->getParameterBag()->all();
```

Which gives me an interesting list of parameters but I don't see the ones related to security.yml (despite the fact that security.yml is imported properly in the config.yml)

```
imports:
- { resource: parameters.yml }
- { resource: security.yml }
- { resource: services.yml }
```

Here is the security.yml. I want to read the value of remember_me lifetime.

```
security:
encoders:
    FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

providers:
    fos_userbundle:
        id: fos_user.user_provider.username

firewalls:
    main:
        pattern: ^/
        form_login:
            check_path: /login_check
            login_path: /login
            always_use_default_target_path: false
            default_target_path: /main
            provider: fos_userbundle
            csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider
        remember_me:
            key: '%secret%'
            lifetime: 60
            path: /
            domain: ~
        logout:       true
        anonymous:    true

access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Only things under parameters end up in the parameter bag.  Most config options are processed under the dependency injection configuration and end up being injected into services.  Fire walls in particular are complicated.  You can take a look at the SecurityBundle DependencyInjection stuff to see if remember_me ends up being accessible somewhere.  But your best bet is to just add your own parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Make remember_me.lifetime a parameter:

```
#parameters.yml
parameters:
    remember_me.lifetime: 60
```

And in your security config, use the parameter's value as following:

```
#security.yml
security:
    firewalls:
         ....
         main:
             remember_me:
                 key: '%secret%'
                 lifetime: '%remember_me.lifetime%'
```

You'll be then able to access this parameters from the bag or inject it into any service.